# How do I create a loop based on a series of points in TikZ as in the Graph style?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am currently working on a project to create a translator from [Frank Drewes' graph style](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~drewes/graphs/) into TikZ.

As an example, I am trying to recreate the following diagram from the graph style manual into a TikZ diagram.

(See [Example graph style diagram](http://www-student.cs.york.ac.uk/~jw514/loop.png))

[image]

The code for the above in Graph style is:

```
\begin{graph}(4,4)(-2,0)
\squarenode{Sq}(-1.5,3.5)
\textnode{Te}(1.5,3.5){abc}
\roundnode{Ro}(0,.5)
\diredge{Sq}{Te}
\edge{Sq}{Ro} \diredge{Ro}{Te}
\dirbow{Ro}{Sq}{-.2}
\dirbow{Ro}{Te}{.2}
\dirloopedge{Ro}(-.8,-.2)(-1.2,.4)
\dirloopedge{Ro}(.8,-.2)(1.2,.4)
\loopedge{Ro}{15}(0,-.5)
\end{graph}
```

Most of these commands are easy to translate; however, I am having a lot of trouble with the "loopedge" and "dirloopedge" commands.

The description of the "loopedge" command from the manual is as follows:

> \loopedge{name}(x1,y1)(x2,y2)
>
> A loop at node name. The coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are interpreted as relative coordinates of the endpoints of two edge halves starting in name. During drawing, these are connected by a curve to obtain a loop.

There does not seem to be a command anything like this in TikZ and, in fact, drawing loops seems to be really difficult. My problem is further compounded by a lack of documentation in the graph style manual as to how the connecting curve is actually produced.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what method is used to obtain the curve drawn by `\dirloopedge` (for some reason, the asymmetric support points in your example seem to yield a symmetric curve). Below is a macro that has the same form as that in "Graph Style".

It draws a straight line from the start node to the first support point and from the second support curve to the start node, with a curve between the two support points with the `out` and `in` angles equal to the angles of the straight line segments. You might want to adjust the `looseness` parameter, which determines the radius of the curve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\dirloopedge#1(#2,#3)(#4,#5){
    \pgfpointxy{#2}{#3}
    \pgfgetlastxy{\ax}{\ay}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\outangle{atan2(#2,#3)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\inangle{atan2(#4,#5)}

    \draw [-latex] (#1) -- +(#2,#3) to [out=\outangle,in=\inangle,looseness=5]  +(#4,#5) -- (Ro);
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (Ro)  at (0,0.5) [fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] {};

\dirloopedge{Ro}(0.8,-0.2)(0.8,0.2)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: dirloopedge with TikZ]